# getlastrow() for a specific Column or Ignore Formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a simple form in google sheets that adds my inputs from Cells B1-B12 to a table.  It works perfectly, except instead of adding my entry to the next blank row, it adds it to row 501. The reason for this is because several columns include formulas that go down to row 500, so it seems getlastrow() is taking into consideration all cells that include no values, but formulas.

I think this can be solved by either:

1.) Specifying getlastrow() starting from column G, which doesn't include any formula fields

2.) Somehow ignoring formula fields when using the getlastrow() function

I've exhausted my google/stack overflow searches, so if anyone has any ideas on how I can tweak my code to accomplish 1 or 2, I would very much appreciate it!

```js
  // Clear Form
  function ClearCell() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS =ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Sold"); //FormSheet
    

  var rangesToClear = ["B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10","B11","B12"];
   for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
     formS.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
   }
  }

//---------------------------------------------------------

  function SubmitData(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet / Data

    var values = [[formS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B3").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B5").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B9").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B11").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B12").getValue()]];
    dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,7,1,12).setValues(values);
    ClearCell()

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "B1:B12" and want to put the next row of the last row of the column "G" from the column "G" to the column direction. And, you want to clear the cells of "B1:B12".

#### Modification points:

- At `ClearCell()`, I think that the process cost might be able to be reduced a little using the range list.
- At `SubmitData()`, I think that the values of cells "B1:B12" can be retrieved by one call of `getValues`.
- `getLastRow` returns the last row of data range including the values and formulas. It seems that this is the current specification.

  - In this modification, the last row of the column "G" is retrieved using `isBlank()`.
- `ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Sold")` can be used one time.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function ClearCell(formS) {
  var rangesToClear = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12"];
  formS.getRangeList(rangesToClear).clearContent();
}

function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Sold");
  var values = formS.getRange("B1:B12").getValues().flat();
  for (var r = formS.getLastRow(); r >= 1; r--) {
    if (!formS.getRange("G" + r).isBlank()) {
      formS.getRange(r + 1, 7, 1, 12).setValues([values]);
      break;
    }
  }
  ClearCell(formS);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())
- [isBlank()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isblank)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried the modified SubmitData function, but upon submitting my form, it did not add the data to the table.  I played around a bit and the following modified SubmitData function seemed to do the trick.  Thank you again for taking the time to respond!! It gave me some ideas to work with :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function SubmitData(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet / Data

    var values = [[formS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B3").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B5").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B9").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B11").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B12").getValue()]];
    dataS.getRange(getLastRowByDirectionUp(dataS, "G")+1,7,1,12).setValues(values);
    ClearCell();
  }


function getLastRowByDirectionUp(sheet, col) {
  if(sheet.getRange(col + sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()=="") {
    return sheet.getRange(col + sheet.getLastRow()).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
  else {
    return sheet.getLastRow();
  }
} function SubmitData(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Sold"); //Data Entry Sheet / Data

    var values = [[formS.getRange("B1").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B2").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B3").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B4").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B5").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B6").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B7").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B8").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B9").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B10").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B11").getValue(),
    formS.getRange("B12").getValue()]];
    dataS.getRange(getLastRowByDirectionUp(dataS, "G")+1,7,1,12).setValues(values);
    ClearCell();
  }


function getLastRowByDirectionUp(sheet, col) {
  if(sheet.getRange(col + sheet.getLastRow()).getValue()=="") {
    return sheet.getRange(col + sheet.getLastRow()).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
  else {
    return sheet.getLastRow();
  }
}
```